# what is the alternative to the matlab's built-in function : strrep

Tags: matlab

looking at a phones keypad. each number has three letter associated with it , except 1 and 0. how can i replace letters with the associated number without using the built in function 'strrep'? if input is MATLAB , output will be 628522
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy to do using `containers.Map`:

```
c = containers.Map({'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'}, ...
    [2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9,9]) ;

testStr = 'MATLAB' ;
testOut = NaN(1,numel(testStr)) ;
for ii = 1:numel(testStr)
    testOut(ii) = c(lower(testStr(ii))) ;
end
```

result:

```
>> testOut

testOut =

     6     2     8     5     2     2
```

Comment: this is the original qtns :                       Each number on telephone keypads, except 0 and 1, corresponds to a set of uppercase letters
as shown in this list:
2ABC, 3DEF, 4GHI, 5JKL, 6MNO, 7PQRS, 8TUV, 9WXYZ
Hence, a phone-number specification can include uppercase letters and digits. Write a function called dial that takes as its input argument a string of length 16 or less that includes only these characters and returns as its output argument the telephone number as a uint64. Here is the input and output for one example of a call of the function:
don't use built-in function strrep

Comment: how can i adjust the code such that it takes inputs like ('1FUNDOG4YOU'). i decided to put numbers from 0 to 9 into both sides of the container but matlab rejected that

Comment: @OlubukolaOgunsola that was *not* your original question. Read your question again. The solution is to put numbers on both sides of the map, as you say. But I can't help you debug it if you don't even provide an error message.